# How do I make images accessible for screenreaders in my webpage? What does it mean when an image is accessible?

Tags: html, image

These are my 2 images elements and I have added the `title` and `alt` attributes:

```
<img src="images/dog.jpg" title="dog" alt="Picture of a dog">
<img src="images/dog-house.jpg" title="dog in house" alt="Picture of a dog in it's house">
```

So how do I make these 2 images accessible and is this enough for an image to be considered accessible?

Comment: please refactor your code in the question posting the correct code, that is not valid HTML

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Accessibility isn't a binary state. There are degrees of accessibility. But, this is a really broad topic. The W3C has [pages of information on the subject](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/). It's also worth reading [this essay on alt text](https://web.archive.org/web/20100314215430/http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your `<img>` tags you have posted, I am going to recommend you things that will help your webpage with be more accessible to screenreaders.

- Don't provide an `alt` text for images with captions and decorations

If your images are grouped with a caption already describing them or are used for decoration only. In these cases, alt text may seem redundant or unnecessary. In situations when an image is already explained with text content or does not add meaning to a page, the `<img>` still needs an `alt` attribute, but it can be set to an *empty* string. Here's an example:

```
    <img src="visualDecoration.jpeg" alt="">
```

- Don't write `alt` tags for the sake of SEO

Stuffing your `alt` tags with keywords is likely to hurt your search engine ranking rather than help it, as you may be viewed as spam.

- Keep unique `alt` tags

Along with keyword stuffing, using the same `alt` tags and keywords for multiple images may appear as spam. Each image should have a unique `alt` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can access the image in html. But make sure that the folder and the image are correct. For example if the image is in folder than the src should be folder/image.jpg. If the image is together with the html pages than just add the image.jpg in src.

```
<img src="images/dog.jpg" alt="Picture of a dog">
  <img src="images/dog-house.jpg" alt="Picture of a dog>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, does doing this make the image accessible for the screenreaders?

Comment: This is the way to load image in html. Just make sure of the image location in src is correct and it should work fine